# Where to put console log in axios get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to create a function to grab my profile data from LinkedIn. For debugging though I need to see what data is being mapped over or before that. But not sure where to put my console log to see the data its receiving. Any help is much appreciated :)

```
// Grabs profile data from the json url
private getProfiles() {
let config = {
  headers: {'Authorization':'Bearer AQVVEqG......'}
}
axios
  .get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me", config)
  .then(response => 
      response.data.map(profile => ({
        name: `${ profile.localizedLastName }`,
      }))
    )
    .then(profiles => {
      this.setState({
        profiles,
        isLoading: false
      });
    })
  // We can still use the `.catch()` method since axios is promise-based
  .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
```

}

Comment: you are not returning anything from the first Promise.then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put it in the callback function.

```
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  response.data.map(profile => ({
    name: `${ profile.localizedLastName }`,
  }))
})
.then(profiles => {
  console.log(profiles);
  this.setState({
    profiles,
    isLoading: false   
  });
})
```

Comment: wrap inside `{ }` in first then.

Comment: And return something from the first `then`.

Comment: Thank you! Still new to back end developing... :)

Comment: Will accept your answer in 3 minutes when it lets me

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
.then(response => {
  console.log(response);
  response.data.map(profile => ({
    name: `${ profile.localizedLastName }`,
  }))
})
```